# Accessing array in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have given
time = [ 5 , 7 , 10 , 15 , 30 , 50 , 70 , 100 , 120 , 150 ] , stocks = [1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1] , and repetation = [ 0 , 1 , 2, 3, 4 ,5 , 6 ,7, 8, 9]

Now i want to access time and stocks according to the repetation array like

time[0] , time[1]  like time[repetation first value ]  and so on.

```
{% for n in repetation %}
                <div class="stockDataDiv">
                    <span>
                        {{ time.n }}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        {{ stockRequired.n }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

This is the code that i tried but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare a filter

```py
@register.filter
def index(value, index):
    return value[int(index)]
```

```
{% for n in repetation %}
                <div class="stockDataDiv">
                    <span>
                        {{ time|index:n }}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        {{ stockRequired|index:n }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) is the doc on how to write your own filters